# Do these sentences form right?

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

> I want to marry a girl in outer nation **there**.

Is the use of 'there' is justified?

> I would like to establish a position preferably without him getting a grain of sand **in** his face.

When it says 'in', we are specifically talking your parts in which sand can go in-mouth,ear,eyes,etc.When I say, 'I slap you **on** your face',I mean parts -like chick,forehead,etc.Am I right  or the sentence has a problem?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "outer nation." Yes you can get sand in your face, but it doesn't necessarily mean *into* any particular facial opening. It sometimes implies *eyes*, but you can also say *get sand in your eyes  and mouth, or ears or nose* –this gets down to the, uh, nitty gritty. Slap on the face usually refers to the cheek, but it could refer to somewhere else, such as across the eyes. But it wouldn't usually mean on the forehead, since that's the top-most part of the face. You could designate slap on the forehead. Again  be specific in your language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence doesn't really make much sense. Maybe you could say something like:

> I want to marry a girl in the outer states/regions/provinces.

*Nations* and *outer* don't really go together well. *There* shouldn't be used. If you really want to use *there*, you could say:

> I want to marry a girl *out there* in the outer provinces.

In the second sentence, it's better to say *on your face* instead of *in your face*. If you say *in your face*, people will think the sand is getting into the skin of the face. (Very painful!) You *can* say ***in*** the eyes/mouth/nose.

Answer (score 2):

The correct idiom is

> sand in his face

which generally means directly at his face or in the direction of his face.

[image: here]
[image: here]